# Restart Connector at timed intervals

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have a JDBC connector on an oracle base, however, sometimes the connector stops receiving data from the DB. Sometimes the task indicates an error, sometimes not.

The only way I found to solve this problem was to restart the task at timed intervals. Considering that, is there any way to do this directly in Kafka, more specifically in the source connector yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on another Stack Overflow solution, I used a Kubernetes `CronJob` to do this. The `CronJob` below kills the connect pod on a daily basis. (This is the only I found to solve the problem).

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: kill-connect-pod
spec:
  schedule: "0 8 * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: kafka-connect-killer
          containers:
          - name: kill-connect-pod
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh 
            - -c
            - |
              kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods | grep ^edh-connect | awk '{print $1}')
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```